# perma link redirect 301 wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, seo

To change the permalink of my site from /%postname%/ to /%postname%-1/, I need a 301 redirect code and I don’t want to use a plugin.
What code should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Make a complete backup of your .htaccess file before changing anything.  Try this:

1. Log in to your WordPress dashboard and navigate to Settings > Permalinks.
2. Select the "Custom Structure" option and enter /%postname%-1/ in the field.
3. Save changes to update your permalink structure.

Then add this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1-1/ [R=301,L]
```